# How to optimize expression to avoid evaluation timeout?

Tags: jsonata

When working with a limited dataset my jsonata expression works as intended, but with a larger one I keep getting "Expression evaluation timeout: Check for infinite loop". Is there any way to optimize this expression to avoid timeouts?

Check [try.jsonata.org/ryGcRwxkr](http://try.jsonata.org/ryGcRwxkr) for an example with a working dataset.
Please try pasting [this json](https://github.com/churruarin/static/raw/master/geojson/test.json).

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": $map($[0].features, function($v){
      {
        "type": $v.type,
        "geometry": $v.geometry,
        "properties": $merge([$v.properties,{"fecha":$$[1][tm=$v.properties.tm].fecha}])
       }
      })
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I found it is a limitation of the JSONata Excerciser. Anyway I'd like to optimize the expression because it is very resource demanding. Thanks again!

Comment: How did you find out that it is a limitation?